# Using multiple sessions with androids facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook

for my App I am using the facbeook sdk to let the user login to my app.

Now I want to allow the connection between two accounts by using facebook. The problem is that I would need a new facebook-session-object that forces the user to login even if a user is logged in.

The only thing I need from that user after he logged hin: ID and AccessToken.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? If you want access to two different FB accounts, wouldn't you expect the user to login twice?